# Django unittest - How to disable console logging only

Tags: django, python-unittest

I have a test in django (v2.2) that generates an error on purpose to check that errors are logged in the proper log files.

But I get also a print in the console which is kind of annoying, I was looking for a way to hide the message.

If I disable logging with `logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL)`, it will not log the error in the files.

I also tried to use `with self.settings(LOGGING=logging)` after removing the console handler from the loggers (see settings below) but it does not seem to be taken into account.

Also, setting `disable_existing_logger` to **True** does not help.

Do you have some ideas how to do that?

---

my settings:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'msg_filter': {
            '()': MessageFilter,
            'strings_to_be_ignored': [
                'Not Found: /favicon.ico'
            ],
        }
    },
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '_____________________________________________________________'
            '\n%(asctime)s - [%(levelname)s|%(name)s] %(message)s\n'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s - [%(levelname)s|%(name)s] %(message).50s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'warning': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/some_folder/warning.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'filters': ['msg_filter']
        },
        'warning_simple': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/some_folder/warning.log',
            'formatter': 'simple',
            'filters': ['msg_filter']
        },
        'info': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': '/some_folder/info.log',
            'maxBytes': 1024 * 1024 * 2,
            'backupCount': 9,
            'formatter': 'simple',
            'filters': ['msg_filter']
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'filters': ['msg_filter']
        },
        'console_simple': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple',
            'filters': ['msg_filter']
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'info', 'warning'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console_simple', 'info', 'warning_simple'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set `disable_existing_loggers` variable `True`. This variable being true means the loggers is disabled.
Read this:

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/logging/#configuring-logging

Comment: Hi @Meshkat, thanks for your answer, unfortunately I tried that without success. I made a mistake in the description, I meant "Also, setting disable_existing_logger to **True** does not help.", it's corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the `--logging-clear-handlers` option.

`python manage.py test --logging-clear-handlers`